# 5 cards from a 52 card deck, what is the probability that the sum of cards is greater than 48

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, card-games

The problem states: 
$5$ cards are dealt from a standard $52$ card deck. What is the probability that the sum of the values on the five cards is $48$ or more?

It is assumed of course that the value of face cards is $10$ and that of aces $11$. I know I am looking for the ratio between the number of possible outcomes with sum of values at least $48$, and the total number of possible outcomes, but I am having trouble finding the former quantity.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think the only solution is to casework. You will have to consider cases where the sum is equal to $48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53$ or $54$.

Comment: This seems like a job for brute force case-by-case based on the smallest card.  If you have a $4$, all of the remaining cards must be aces.  If you have a $5$ all of the remaining cards must be aces or three aces and a face card.  If you have a $6$ it could be $69AAA,~6FFAA,~6FAAA,~6AAAA$ etc... You can count how many hands fall into the $6FFAA$ category for example by picking which $6$, which two face cards, and which two aces for a total of $4\cdot \binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.  This will be tedious, but it will eventually yield a solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz it's actually even worse than that as you also have to count all possible combinations for the higher sums as well, since the questions asks for all combinations whose sum is **at least** 48.

Comment: @MichaelWang I already accounted for that in my comment, note that $6AAAA$ has a different total than $69AAA$.  Whether you break into cases based on the sum or based on the lowest card, they both accomplish the same thing of beginning to partition the valid arrangements into smaller sets.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh right, sorry. I should have taken more time to read, oops. However, you also have to account for cases when the lowest card is a $7$, $8$, $9$, etc.

Comment: @MichaelWang hence the "etc..." I wasn't going to write out each and every case in a comment.......... just the first few so the OP could see where I was going with the setup

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways to do it.

A) 4 aces and a card between 4 and 10.

B) 3 aces and two cards whose sum is 15 or higher and whose values are between 5 and 10.

C) 2 aces and three cards whose sum is 26 or higher and whose values are between 6 and 10.

D) 1 ace and 4 cards whose sum is 37 or higher and whose values are between 7 and 10.

E) no aces and 5 cards whose sum is 48 or higher and whose values are between 8 and 10.

So

A) there is one way to have 4 aces.  And there are 40 cards between $4$ and $10$.  (Ten ranks, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K and 4 suits.  So A) is 40.

B) There are 4 ways to have 3 aces.  And the ways to have two cards add to more than 15 are

B1) two 10s.  There are $12*11/2$ ways to do this.

B2) a ten and a card between 5 and 9.  There are $12$ tens and $5*4$ cards between 5 and 9.  So there are $240$ ways to do this.

B3) 2 9s.  There are $4*3/2=6$ ways to do this.

B4) A 9 and a card betweem 6 and 8. There are $4*(3*4) = 48$ ways to do this.

B5) two 8s.  There are $4*3/2=6$ ways to do this.

B6) an 8 and a 7.  There are $4*4=16$ ways to do this.

So B1) = $4*12*11/2$;B2) $4*240$; B3) $4*6$; B4) =$4* 48$ B5) $4*6$; B6) = $4*16$

C) there are $3*4/2$ ways to pick two aces. Two pick three cards that are 26 or higher between $6$ and $10$ are

C1) Three 10s.  There are $12*11*10/3!$ ways to do this.

C2) Two 10s. and a card between $6$ and $9$.  There are $12*11/2$ times $4*4$ ways to do this.

C3) One 10. and two 9s.  There are $12$ times $4*3/2$ ways to do this.

C4) A 10, a 9, and a 7 or an 8.  There are $4*4$ times $2*4$ ways to do this.

C5) A 10, and two 8s.   There are $4$ times $4*3/2$ ways to do this.

C6) three 9s.  There are $4$ ways to do this.

C7) two 9s and an 8.  There are $4*3/2$ times $4$ ways to do this.

D) there are $4$ ways to have one ace.  The ways to have 4 carsd whose sum is 37 or higher for $7$ through $10$ is:

D1) four tens:  $12*11*10*9/4!$ ways to do that.

D2) three tens: and a $7$, $8$ or $9$.  $4$ times $3*4$ ways to do that

D3) two 10s, two nines.  there are $4*3/2$ times $4*3/2$ ways to do that.

D4) two 10s, a nine and an eight.  There are $4*3/2$ times $4*4$ ways to do that.

D5) one 10, 3 nines.  There are $4$ times $4*3/2$ ways to do that.

E) the ways to do this are

E1) five 10s.  There are $12*11*10*9*8/5!$ ways to do that.

E2) four 10s and an 8 or 9.  There are $12*11*10*9/4!$ times $8$ ways to do that.

E3) three 10s and two 9s.  There are ${12\choose 3}$ times ${4 \choose 3}$ ways to do that.

Multiply and add them up and divide by ${52 \choose 5}$.

Comment: This would make for a decent recursive program.  By hand though... difficult.

Comment: Wouldn't you multiply B1-B6 by 4, since there are 4 ways to get 3 aces?

Comment: Oops.  Typo disconnect somewhere along the line.  It was four when I started typing. Somehow by the time I got to the end it became a three in my mind (because I was thinking three aces; who knows.  It was an error.)

Comment: Also a lot of them I should have written as ${12 \choose 4}$ rather than $12*11*10*9/4!$ but somehow I started typing and ... that came out.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried various methods to avoid *brute force* and came up empty.  Among other problems, the interaction of the $10$'s is a killer.  Attempting to use Stars and Bars as a *guide* to outlining the solutions may be a cure that is worse than the disease.  The one thing that I didn't try, because I am uneducated in this area, is some sort of variation of generating functions.

Comment: @user2661923: You can deal with the tens straightforwardly using generating functions if the problem were with replacement. Without replacement I can't think of anything yet.

Comment: @BrianTung Unsure what you are saying.  On MathSE, I have seen many examples of generating function solutions, where the person answering concluded with (in effect) "...the coefficient of ... in the equation ...".  This begs the question of finding an elegant way of explicitly computing the coefficient, without computer software.  Assuming that the problem is with replacement, are you saying that the final numerical answer can be elegantly computed?  ...see next comment

Comment: @BrianTung Admittedly, even if you are not saying that, I (personally) regard the generating function approach as extremely valuable.  It cuts through the analysis and allows the computations to be quickly/efficiently organized and expressed.

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible hands, even treating every card as unique, is only $\binom{52}{5} = 2598960$, which is well within brute-force range of a computer.

It's possible to do better, i.e. jointly polynomial in the deck size, hand size, and range of card values, using a dynamic programming algorithm. We can find the distribution of the sum of 5 cards drawn from the deck by iterating over the number of aces $i = 0 \ldots 5$ we could potentially draw:

- Recursively compute the distribution of the sum of $5 - i$ cards drawn from a deck without aces, memoizing the solution.
- Add the value of the $i$ aces.

and then binomially weighting the contributions for each $k$. The recursive calls then compute the sum of $0 \ldots 5$ cards drawn from a deck with the 10s/faces also removed, then the 9s also removed, and so forth until only 2s are left. This corresponds to the decomposition of the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) as a product of binomials.

I've implemented this in my [Icepool Python library](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool). You can [run this script](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/icecup.html?c=GYJw9gtgBAlgxgUwA5jAG1hFIAuUAiCcA1gFCkAmRxUAvAdQBQDaAjKwDRQBMXAzFwAsXAKxcAbFwDsXABxcAnF1YAGZWqir1AXS44YEBAGdaggJTkkIGADscjKiQukwAVxxJ3D6gDoqAQzRGETMfI1cIRjMLIA) online:

```
from icepool import Deck

deck = Deck([11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10], times=4)
output(deck.deal(5).sum())
```

The result is that 55580 out of 2598960 possible hands sum to at least 49, or about 2.14%. Compare 2.60% with replacement (e.g. dice rather than cards).

This approach can be extended to find X-of-a-kind, straights, and more. If you are curious to learn more, you can read [my paper on the subject](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool/blob/main/papers/icepool_preprint.pdf).

```
@inproceedings{liu2022icepool,
    title={Icepool: Efficient Computation of Dice Pool Probabilities},
    author={Albert Julius Liu},
    booktitle={Eighteenth AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Interactive Digital Entertainment},
    volume={18},
    number={1},
    pages={258-265},
    year={2022},
    month={Oct.},
    eventdate={2022-10-24/2022-10-28},
    venue={Pomona, California},
    url={https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AIIDE/article/view/21971},
    doi={10.1609/aiide.v18i1.21971}
}
```